# Do I really need Magento over WooCommerce

Tags: magento2

I'm going to build an online store for our local store.

I have a decent WordPress experience, but I'm doing a research if I'm better off building it with Magento.

From what I have found out, in case you have a lot of products, it's best to go with Magento. We will probably have around 2000 products at the start and will go to up to 10000 in up to 1-2 years.

It will be mainly a store, rather than a blog.

However, Im not sure if we are able to afford a big VPS at the moment, as we are not sure if we will have a lot of orders at the start. Adding the fact that I will spend a ton of time to learn Magento, is it really necessary to go with Magento??

My plan is to start off with WooCommerce and then learn Magento over one year period. Then use a tool to migrate all the products from WordPress to the new Magento store I will build, in case we decide it's worth the time/money.

This way I will see if it will have any sales and if it will be worth taking a server with a lot of resources and spending the time to build a Magento store from scratch with no experience and a lot of time spent learning it.

Can anyone advise me if my plan seems legit? Please add any advise you believe will be useful in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your plan is to go with Magento anyway within a year, I think you should come up with reasons to not use magento out of the gate. Building a woocommerce/wordpress store with the plan of getting rid of it within a year seems like a waste of your time. Site setup/data migrations generally require a decent amount of effort. If the plan is truly to go to Magento within a year or two, just start with it. Your time is valuable :).

Comment: I completely agree with you... It's just that the store will be built for a very close person and I really want to provide them with the best. That's why I'm wondering so much regarding what should I choose... After all, even if it's a WooCommerce, what could go wrong in case I have a lot of products.